# Web scraping for multiple classes using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, beautifulsoup, edgar

I am trying to scrape address from 10K filing document in HTML: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1652044/000165204419000032/goog10-qq32019.htm

It has multiple div class, and I want to scrape for address inside span.

Expected output:

1600 Amphitheatre parkway

I have tried few things like below:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1652044/000165204419000032/goog10-qq32019.htm')
r

add1 = r.html.find_all('div')
add1
```

However,  if you inspect the page it has many layers I am new to HTML and python. Please help

Comment: Make your life easier and use their [official API](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/sec-api-documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this, but I'm not sure it's very robust, or applicable to many examples given how the ids look...

[image]

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()
page = session.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1652044/000165204419000032/goog10-qq32019.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find(id="d92517213e644-wk-Fact-0B11263160365DBABCF89969352EE602")
print(content.text)
```

output

```
1600 Ampitheatre Parkway
```

Edit : I didn't see @baduker answer and I didn't know there was an API, he is right, use the API

Comment: I tried this but however, ids doesn't match is there we can use any other argument other than id to get the company address